# ipad : event.touches is randomly undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have some simple code that is controlling a slider control on an iPad.  I'm running into an issue where the control is jumping around wildly and I traced it down to the fact that `ev.originalEvent.touches` is sometimes `undefined`...

Wondering if anyone has any idea what might be going on here.  jQuery 1.7.2, iOS5.1, iPad 3 if it matters

```
$( document.body )
    .on( 'mousemove touchmove', function( ev ){
        // logs undefined about 10% of the time???
        console.log( ev.originalEvent.touches );
    } );
```

And of course I can't re-produce this in a simple stripped-down case, though this is the *exact* code that's running: http://jsfiddle.net/vYKhh/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you are using the 'touchmove' or 'mousemove' event the touches array is 'ev.touches' so try this:

```
$( document.body )
.on( 'mousemove touchmove', function( ev ){
    // logs undefined about 10% of the time???
    console.log( ev.touches );
} );
```

But for 'mousedown' and 'touchstart' it's still ev.originalEvent.touches.